# Grails: groovy.sql.Sql and Model.withTransaction what happens?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-orm

Grails GORM `withTransaction` and `groovy.sql.Sql` will use the same connection if I put the sql call of the stored procedure inside `withTransaction`? For example:

Lets say i have a command:

```
@Validateable
class MyCommand {
  List<MyModel> listOfModel
}
```

and then I have a service to handle this command

```
class MyService {
  def dataSource

  def handleCommand( MyCommand command ) {
    MyModel.withTransaction { status ->
      for( MyModel m : command.listOfModel ) {
         if( !m.save() ) {
           status.setRollbackOnly()
           throw new MyException(m.errors)
         }
      }

      //now I need to call a stored proc. This will use the same connection?
      //withTransaction will commit the call?
      Sql s = new Sql(dataSource)
      s.call('my_stored_proc')
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found how to do this.

```
def sessionFactory

//after GORM saves...  
sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
Sql s = new Sql( sessionFactory.currentSession.connection()  )
s.call()
```

More info in [this topic](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Stored-Procedures-GORM-td3901546.html).